# Shorten Repeating PHP variable POST declaration

Tags: php

So i'll have this code for declare a variable until 6, is it a possible way i can shorten the code?

```
    //Get POST Data
    $nama_anggota1 = $_POST['nama_anggota1'];
    $email_anggota1 = $_POST['email_anggota1'];
    $discord_anggota1 = $_POST['discord_anggota1'];
    $telp_anggota1 = $_POST['telp_anggota1'];
    $id_anggota1 = $_POST['id_anggota1'];
    $nick_anggota1 = $_POST['nick_anggota1'];
    
    $nama_anggota2 = $_POST['nama_anggota2'];
    $email_anggota2 = $_POST['email_anggota2'];
    $discord_anggota2 = $_POST['discord_anggota2'];
    $telp_anggota2 = $_POST['telp_anggota2'];
    $id_anggota2 = $_POST['id_anggota2'];
    $nick_anggota2 = $_POST['nick_anggota2'];
```

as so on repeat until 6

this is my html code

```
                <div class="box">
                    <label for="nama">Nama</label>
                    <input type="text" required name="nama_anggota${no}">
                </div>
                <div class="box">
                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" required name="email_anggota${no}">
                </div>
                <div class="box">
                    <label for="">Discord</label>
                    <input type="text" required name="discord_anggota${no}">
                </div>
                <div class="box">
                    <label for="">No. Telp</label>
                    <input type="tel" required name="telp_anggota${no}">
                </div>
                <div class="box">
                    <label for="">ID In Game</label>
                    <input type="text" required name="id_anggota${no}">
                </div>
                <div class="box">
                    <label for="">Nickname In Game</label>
                    <input type="text" required name="nick_anggota${no}">
                </div>
```

thank you :)

Comment: Create an array for each variable that contains 6 elements and then iterate from 1 to 6 to fetch all the POST variables. It's a little bit time consuming.

Comment: Don't create separate variables in the first place? What's the advantage of `$nama_anggota1` over `$_POST['nama_anggota1']`?

Comment: Might perhaps also make more sense to change the structure of the data you receive via POST in the first place, depending on where that is coming from. Form fields can be named to automatically create arrays, so that no `…1`, `…2`, … suffixes would need to come into play to begin with.

Comment: do you know `for` loops?

Comment: Name your form fields `name="anggota[${no}][email]"`, then just use the `$_POST` data structure as is, which will look like `$_POST['anggota'][0]['email']`…

Answer (score 1):

You should be receiving the data in a different way. It seems more correct that you receive an **array** of users.

In your page you would have something like:

```
            <div class="box">
                <label for="nama">Nama</label>
                <input type="text" required name="anggotas[${no}]['nama']">
            </div>
            <div class="box">
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input type="email" required name="anggotas[${no}]['email']">
            </div>
            <div class="box">
                <label for="">Discord</label>
                <input type="text" required name="anggotas[${no}]['discord']">
            </div>
            <div class="box">
                <label for="">No. Telp</label>
                <input type="tel" required name="anggotas[${no}]['telp']">
            </div>
            <div class="box">
                <label for="">ID In Game</label>
                <input type="text" required name="anggotas[${no}]['id']">
            </div>
            <div class="box">
                <label for="">Nickname In Game</label>
                <input type="text" required name="anggotas[${no}]['nick']">
            </div>
```

And then in your server side:

```
    $anggotas = $POST['anggotas'];
```

And then you have an array of users in your `$anggotas` variable